# Strange issue with replaceAll() in java

Tags: java, json

```
String random = "{\"url\":\"api.github.com/repos/SparkTC/stocator/issues/comments/206712399\",\"html_url\":\"github.com/SparkTC/stocator/issues/22#issuecomment-206712399\"";
System.out.println(random.replaceAll("\\\"", ""));

Output: {"url":"api.github.com/repos/SparkTC/stocator/issues/comments/206712399","html_url":"github.com/SparkTC/stocator/issues/22#issuecomment-206712399"
```

But when I have same content in a file and use the following code, nothing changes.

```
File file = new File("/Users/ayacs/Desktop/example.json");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line = "", oldtext = "";
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            oldtext += line + "\r\n";
        }
        reader.close();

        String newtext = oldtext.replaceAll("\\\"", "\"");
        System.out.println(oldtext);
        System.out.println(newtext);
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("/Users/ayacs/Desktop/example.json");
        writer.write(newtext);
        writer.close();
```

and the output is same as the file content:

```
{\"url\":\"api.github.com/repos/SparkTC/stocator/issues/comments/206712399\",\"html_url\":\"github.com/SparkTC/stocator/issues/22#issuecomment-206712399\"
```

I think I'm having some problem with removing the \ in my file. I looked into other replaceAll problems posted too and tried but none were useful in my case.

Comment: Don't do that.  You should use a JSON parser.

Comment: It sounds like you're actually just seeing string escapes, and you don't have any kind of problem.

Comment: why do you use `.replaceAll()`, not `.replace()`? You don't need a regex here.

Comment: @SLaks Which JSON Parser do you recommend? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should write instead `replace("\\\"", "\"")`.

The method [`replaceAll()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) takes a regex pattern as the first argument and a regex replacement as the second argument. The method [`replace()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-) takes two plain strings and does not apply any interpretation to them.

When you called `replaceAll("\\\"", "\"")`, the program uses the regex string `\"` and replaces it with the string `"`. But the regex string `\"` simply means `"`, because you are escaping the double-quote which has no effect. If you actually wanted to use `replaceAll()` to do the job, you would write `replaceAll("\\\\\"", "\"")`. But this is unnecessarily complicated, so simply use the `replace()` method instead.

Comment: I would have opted for a JSON parser

Comment: Many people think `replace()` replaces just first occurrence. This is a tragically bad choice to name regex-based method `replaceAll()`...

Comment: @SashaSalauyou That would be `replaceFirst()` - which also takes a regex.

Comment: @Nayuki I know that. I'm just trying to explain why people who don't read documentation prefer `replaceAll()` when they see this method next to `replace()` in IDE suggestion.